# Rails active record::not found using friendly id and slug recognition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-activerecord, slug, friendly-id

ive set up my rails app to use friendly_id and paperclip and i've added the slug column to the 'designs' database table using a migration. When I create a new design post and upload my image (using paperclip) the slug column is not updated when I check the database and then I get an active record error, saying the following:

[image]

Here are my code snippets:

Model:

```html
class Design < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :slug
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :img_name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
  :thumb    => ['100x100#',  :jpg, :quality => 70],
  :preview  => ['480>',      :jpg, :quality => 70],
  :large    => ['800>',      :jpg, :quality => 30],
  :retina   => ['1200>',     :jpg, :quality => 30]
},
:convert_options => {
  :thumb    => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
  :preview  => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
  :large    => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
  :retina   => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5'
}
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

Controller:

```html
class DesignsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_design, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @designs = Design.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  def new
    @design = Design.new
  end

  def create
    @design = Design.new(design_params)

    if @design.save
      redirect_to @design, notice: "Hellz yeah, Steve! Your artwork was successfully saved!"
    else
      render 'new', notice: "Oh no, Steve! I was unable to save your artwork!"
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @design.update design_params
      redirect_to @design, notice: "Huzzah! Your artwork was successfully saved!"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @design.destroy
    redirect_to designs_path
  end

  private

  def design_params
    params.require(:design).permit(:img_name, :slug, :image, :caption)
  end

  def find_design
    @design = Design.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

View (#show)

```html
<div id="post_show_content" class="skinny_wrapper wrapper_padding">
    <header>
        <p class="date"><%= @design.created_at.strftime("%A, %b %d") %></p>
        <h1><%= @design.img_name %></h1>
        <hr>
    </header>
          <%= image_tag @design.image.url(:retina), class: "image" %>
        <div class="caption">
          <p><%= @design.caption %></p>
        </div>

    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <div id="admin_links">
        <%= link_to "Edit Artwork", edit_design_path(@design) %>
        <%= link_to "Delete Artwork", design_path(@design), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    

</div>
```

Migration:

```html
class AddSlugToDesigns < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :designs, :slug, :string
    add_index :designs, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: not sure about friendly_id but you can use activerecord find_by `Design.find_by(slug: params[:id])` to get it working

Comment: cheers - sorry, which file do I add that to?

Comment: just replace it on your find_design action on your controller with `@design = Design.find_by(slug: params[:id])`

Comment: I think it is more that when I check the database after creating a post, there is no data in the slug column, it just says NULL. So for some reason when I create a new design - ...designs/new and submit, it adds it to the database, but the slug field is NULL.

Comment: so I tried running `Design.find_each(&:save)` in the rails console, but this didnt fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

use activerecord `find_by` method find your model with slug. your find_design method looks like this

```
class DesignsController < ApplicationController
  def find_design  
    @design = Design.find_by(slug: params[:id])
  end
end
```

in your design model you haven't defined `img_name` (it's a method call) you're referring on `friendly_id :img_name, use: [:slugged, :finders]`
add the following to your model design.rb

```
def img_name
  self.img_name
end
```

An alternative way would be skipping the use of friendly_id gem and write your own method to generate random slug and call it before_validation. something like

```
before_validation :set_slug, :on => :create

def set_slug
  random_token = SecureRandom.hex(3)
  self.slug = "#{self.img_name.downcase}_#{random_token}"
end
```

then use `Design.find_by(slug: params[:id])` on your controllers where you need to query db with slug

Comment: I think it is more that when I check the database after creating a post, there is no data in the slug column, it just says NULL. So for some reason when I create a new design - ...designs/new and submit, it adds it to the database, but the slug field is NULL.

Comment: so I tried running `Design.find_each(&:save)` in the rails console, but this didnt fix it either.

Comment: try adding `img_name` method on your model.

Comment: sorry, that doesnt work. I'm sure it is something with the slug migration to the database and the fact that isnt working. I can create the design post, as when I go to ...designs#index, it is there and on the database, its just the slug isnt picking up the img_title and therefore friendly_id isnt displaying it.

Comment: okay alternatively you can try writing your own method to generate slug and call it `before_validation`  on your model

Comment: cheers for your help but I fixed it - I simply had to add `rails generate friendly_id` before running the migration. I didnt do this as I had previously done this for other models before, but I guess I needed to do it again before adding the slug to the new table.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rails generate friendly_id` prior to running the migration. Even though I had done this before for other models and tables in the database, I need to do this again before running the migration for the new slug in the new table.